# Error in updating app from Google market

Tags: android, google-play

I've developed an application and release it on google market with version 3.0. Later i've done some modification in it and upload new version(3.1) on market. To do this i've first deactivate old version and then upload this new version. Now, when i try to update app in my device (which is having 3.0 version app), i open app page in play store and shocked, because play store page display "OPEN" button inplace of "UPDATE".
Please suggest me the reason for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It takes sometime for new app to get pushed on market. Look at version information on app page.

Comment: Google Play explicitly says "could take a few hours to dispatch" when you upload a new APK... What are you shocked about?

Comment: It is almost 2 days. Google play shows its new version 3.1. But when i want to take update via device then it doesn't come with UPDATE button. Before negative mark any question first clear all things because i've already uploaded many applications on google play. And this is the first app in which i fetch such type of issue  . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How much time has it been when you uploaded the version 3.1 app?

Because it takes some time for google servers to upload the new version to the play store. Pay attention to the instructions, they are not as same as terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Update your apps [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en):

> App updates take some time to be delivered to existing users. If you’ve submitted an update that hasn’t showed up on Google Play, please wait at least 24 hours before contacting our support team.

That also works for updates of course.
Nothing is instant at such a large scale you know...